# Updating a database with two checkboxes checked

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I'm looking for a little help with saving variables, using checkbox selection, to a database. I can individually save each checkbox selection, it is if both checkboxes are selected I am unsure of.

Here are 2 checkboxes

```
<div class="form-check text-start">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="con" id="radio1" value="in"<?=$ac['con']=='in'?' checked':''?>>
</div>
<div class="form-check text-start">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="con" id="radio2" value="out"<?=$ac['con']=='out'?' checked':''?>>
</div>
```

This is the code in a prepared statement that updates the database

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE ac SET 
con = ?
WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->execute([
$_POST['con']
]);
```

If one checkbox is selected it will save as 'in' or 'out' depending which checkbox is selected.

My Question is, If both checkboxes are selected how would I save this third value as say 'value3' or 'In & Out'?

When I try I keep getting just the result of as I had selected one checkbox, so a bit stuck.

Look forward to hearing from someone

Kind Regards

Comment: Both checkboxes have the same name in your form, so only one of their values can be sent to the server. Give them different names and then adjust the php code accordingly to look for both

Comment: @ADyson this is not correct, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: First you have to make a business decision: what does it mean if both checkboxes are selected. We can't make this decision for you. Based on the decisuon, you have to do some data modelling to decide how you store the data. You either want to store the values in separate columns or separate rows.

Comment: @Shadow Perhaps I worded it badly. Yes, the browser will send two parameters, both named "con", but PHP will only put one of them into $_POST["con"], even if both boxes are checked in the form. So it's impossible for the PHP code to tell if both boxes were checked, unless they are given different names

Comment: I wonder what having a status of both 'In' and 'Out' simutaneously actually means. This is reminiscent of Schrödinger's cat. Perhaps what you need here is radio buttons instead of check boxes.

Comment: @ADyson again, not correct. You can use a name ended with square brackets or you can parse the raw input.

Comment: @Shadow you can, but that's not what the OP has done here. Square bracket syntax would get round it and technically yes it's then the same name, fair point, and of course it results in an array at the php end. no-one wants to try and parse the raw input, realistically

Comment: Hi all, many thanks for the responses, being a newby to web design it was a tricky one. After various tries I decided to go with an extra radio button and create a third one called 'In & Out'. This was much easier to pass to the database. Stay Awesome. 

Comment: `an extra radio button`...you mean checkbox? Or did you change it to radios? If you stick with checkboxes, then theoretically the user could select "In", "Out" _and_ "In and Out" all that the same time, and I'm not sure what your server would do with that. Radios probably make more sense, since it sounds like the options should be mutually exclusive. Glad you fixed it, anyway.

Comment: @ADyson, I did change them to radios. I found this much more manageable. Many thanks. Be interesting to know how to save one of three variables using two checkboxes, mission on

Comment: You'd just check the status of both checkboxes in PHP, and have some if or switch logic to decide what value to use, based on the combination of values. (Bear in mind that in HTML forms, if a checkbox isn't checked, no entry is sent to the server at all.)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would you write that 

Comment: Depends on the conditions you want to implement. Do you know how to use an `if` statement in PHP? Do you know how to declare and set a variable? Do you know what rule you want to implement? If so then you have enough information to make an attempt at coding it. (I say this rather than spoon-feeding you a code snippet, because the best way to learn is always to try (and maybe fail) first. If have a few goes and can't make it work, post a new question about it, showing your attempt and explaining where you got stuck.)

Comment: @ADyson, I know a couple of the basics, totally agree with your comment, if stuck I'll reach otherwise I'll gladly post my result and share. Cheers .

Comment: @ADyson, further to above, I ended up going back to 2 checkboxes and saving them as two separate variables this made the next stage of my process a lot more easier to handle. Sometimes applying a bit of simple logic can make things a little easier. Most appreciated 